# Integrating VCS comments in TeamCity with YouTrack issues

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity, issue-tracking, youtrack

I thought I had set this up right but none of the VCS commands seem to be propagating through.

I have a git repository which TeamCity hooks into, when a check-in happens TeamCity runs the build script and creates an artifact. YouTrack has been integrated with TeamCity and has had the projects mapped, so the project build (the one which auto builds and creates an artifact) and it is run on behalf of the admin user (root).

I have told it to process red builds, the mapping maintainer is root, everything else is default. Now both the server and the mapping are ticked as active, and I can see the last Synchronised time, and the build it processed, all of that looks fine, however the commands in the commit were not actioned.

Lets say it processed build 250, which had a VCS comment of:

```
#PMI-52 Fixed
Have finally fixed this annoying issue
```

I would expect task PMI-52 to be moved to the Fixed state, and with Youtrack 4 have the comment below added to the task comments for PMI-52. However none of this happens. So am I missing something or should this put the changes into the tasks/issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectations are completely correct. So the issue must be in the configuration. For the sample you've provided, do you observe the change on 'TeamCity Changes' issue tab of PMI-52? If you do and command there is in red, please consider the error message (click on '?' on the right of the command). The most probable reason is that the integration did not manage to match the TeamCity user to YouTrack user to run the command on behalf of. For the users to match they have to have identical emails.

Comment: I have not added any TeamCity users, do I need to marry up TeamCity users to GIT commiters then and it should work?

Comment: I may be missing something, but I have just created a user with the same username and email address as both my GIT and YouTrack user accounts. I cannot find any option to link this GIT user to the TeamCity user, if I mouse over the committers details in TeamCity it says the TeamCity user is unknown. We are using the professional version at the moment as we are wanting to evaluate before we invest further. I noticed on further inspection that professional edition of TeamCity does not use the installed LDAP plugin which YouTrack and GIT use for their user accounts, so could this be a problem?

Comment: user resolution works in the following manner: TC matches git user to it's own user. For this to happen you need to specify git user name in TC user profile. Then TC user details are retrieved by YouTrack that searches it's own users base and picks the user that has the same email that TC user does. Please mind that it does not matter whether your TC and YT users were created by means of registration form or LDAP integration, what matters is that they have identical emails.

Comment: Thanks I think I have got it working now! it was that last bit I didnt notice.

Comment: Also if you are using console `git commit` the line starting with # are not included. As the comment says: _Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit._

Comment: You can use ^ prefix instead of #.